# C++ Inherited template classes don't have access to the base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am working with template classes for the first time, and trying to figure out why the compiler doesn't seem to like when I use inheritence.

Here is the code:

```
template <typename T>
struct xPoint2
{
    T x;
    T y;

    xPoint2() { x = 0; y = 0; };
};

template <typename T>
struct xVector2 : xPoint2<T>
{
    xVector2() { x = 0; y = 0; };
};
```

The compiler output:

```
vector2.hh: In constructor ‘xVector2<T>::xVector2()’:
vector2.hh:11: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope
vector2.hh:11: error: ‘y’ was not declared in this scope
```

Is it not possible to use templates in this way?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using initializers rather than assignments in class constructors.

Comment: In this particular case, you could also call the base class ctor, because it does the same.

Comment: @Christoph: More accurately, you always call a base class ctor, whether you write such a call or not.  So in this code the assignments in `xVector2()` are redundant - they've already been set to zero by the base constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to help the compiler out by using `this->x` and `this->y`.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates.html#faq-35.19

Answer (score 4):

You must explicitly refer to parent:

```
template <typename T>
struct xVector2 : xPoint2<T>
{
    typedef xPoint2<T> B;
    xVector2() { B::x = 0; B::y = 0; };
};
```