# nested class inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, class, nested

```
template<class T>
class base
{
    class nestedClass
    {
       T pos;
    };
   class derivedClass:public base<T>::nestedClass
     {
       void fun(){
         pos = pos +5; // error: pos is not declared in this scope
        }
     };   

};
```

Comment: That's full of syntax errors.

Comment: sorry, I just simplified from my code.

Comment: Please copy and paste your *real* code. You've obviously omitted a lot of code, and some of what you've left out may be important in determining exactly what's wrong. Create a minimal example that compiles (or that you think *should* compile) and still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Inherited template classes don't have access to the base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810272/c-inherited-template-classes-dont-have-access-to-the-base-class)

Comment: Sean, thank you for pasting real code, but I said a *minimal* example. Theres *way* more code than should be necessary for reproducing the "not declared in this scope" error message. In fact, it doesn't look like this code even exhibits the same problem you started with. Please don't change the goal of the question after people have already started answering. It turns the old answers into nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++03 [Section 14.6/8] says

> When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template definition, the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) are used for nondependent names. The lookup of names dependent on the template parameters is postponed until the actual template argument is known (14.6.2).

Section 14.6.2/3 says

> In the definition of a class template or a member of a class template, if a base class of the class template depends on a template-parameter, the base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

`pos` is an non dependent name so the base class is not examined.

So you have two options.

- Use fully qualified name of Member i.e `base<T>::nestedClass::pos`
- Use `this->pos`.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be explicitly referenced as base::nestedClass::pos  [or use a using statement]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810272/c-inherited-template-classes-dont-have-access-to-the-base-class/4810438#4810438

Comment: If it's a dupe, comment and people will vote to close (and possibly upvote your other answer).

Answer (score 1):

You're not bringing pos into scope.  You can either use `this->pos += 5;` or `using nestedclass::pos`.

Comment: @Prasoon: true... just fixing it when your comment popped up.